set variables in csh script using another file
How can I set a username and password as variables in csh script using files that contain the username or password?
So within the first shell script, something like:
username=*usernamefile.txt*; export username
password=*passwordfile.txt*; export password

Currently in scripts I see the passwords hardcoded but I don't want those in the script, I want to put the username and password into other files and then just point to those for the variables I will call later.
currently, if the username is pleasehelp and the password was 1234, then the current script reads:
username=pleasehelp; export username
password=1234; export password

I took the username and password and created files with just those inputs, but now I need to figure out how to let the script interpret that instead of the hardcoded passwords.
All through subsequent scripts, called from this script, are calls to those variables, so I am trying to only make changes on the declarations if possible.
The references read like this:
${HOME}/sqlplus -s ${username}/${password}@${databasename} /path/sqlfilename

I would like to not change the above line at all.
so if I put the password in a password.txt file, how can I declare that, export as password, and allow the rest of the script run as normal?

Can you change the content of password.txt?

yes, I created the file to contain the password that was previously hardcoded. I want to now export the variable of password using the file.
I attempted to use:
password=$(cat password.txt); export password
That didn't work. I am not sure what the $ is doing there or the ` before and after. I am going to try variations that remove each.

You say _the current script reads:
username=pleasehelp; export username …_ while you speak of a csh script, but this is a syntax error in csh. You have to sort out which scripts executed by which shells you actually use.

Maybe username="`cat usernamefile.txt`". I suggest to use sh or bash for scripting instead of csh.

You can change the runtime configuration file named .csrc in your home directory to instruct the C shell at launch-time.
If you want to set variables for your script, or for interactive use, you can add this to that file:
set username=`cat ${home}/username.txt`
set password=`cat ${home}/password.txt`

This will read the value for the username variable from the file in your home directory named: username.txt.
Please note that saving passwords in plain text files is insecure.
